# Why is the external js file not loading

Tags: node.js, socket.io, chat, ejs, nodemon

Ok, so I am trying to make a project on **chatApps** using Nodejs, Socket.io, EJS, nodemon etc..

So I was just trying to read a working code from https://github.com/ngrt/simpleChatApp

And I created a similar repo myself https://github.com/ayushtues/ChatApp.git

In this basically, there is a server-side file (app.js) which uses express and `app.use(express.static('public'));`so the public folder works as root.

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){

    //displays index.html 
    res.render('index');
});
```

So it uses the `index.ejs` file ....

All this works fine but the problem is

```
  <script  src= "http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>
    <script src="chat.js" ></script>
```

In the `index.ejs` file the chat.js doesn't seem to load in my repo ..while it seems to load in the working repo...

```
> simplechatapp@1.0.0 start /home/ayushtues/new1/simpleChatApp
> nodemon app "run"

[nodemon] 1.14.3
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app run app.js`
New user connected
^C
ayushtues@Kamikaze:~/new1/simpleChatApp$
```

This is the working repo's terminal output and it clearly shows the new user connected...whereas in mine

```
> simpleapp@1.0.0 start /home/ayushtues/simpleApp
> nodemon app "run"

[nodemon] 1.18.9
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching: *.*
[nodemon] starting `node app.js run`
```

After this the new user connected doesn't come ..
So can anybody please help me find the problem ...really stuck here from some time ...

[image]

[image]

Ok well sorry ..didn't knew the browser also had a console ..beginner mistake

Can someone help me debug this

Comment: What does your browser’s dev tools say? Can it download what’s needed? Connect to proper places?

Comment: What's the error you're getting in the browser's console?

Comment: Tip: don't include `node_module` in your repository, add it to `gitignore`, instead only commit `package.json`

Comment: Do you have any error in the Network tab of your development tools?

Comment: please see the updated question